# Embed XUL backend in C

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, embed, xul

I need to write a standalone (not under XULRunner) c/c++ application (Windows OS) that uses XUL as its backend GUI library.

If it is possible, can you give me a link to an example application ? I saw something about libXul, is it needed ? where can i find it ?

TNX, Vertilka

Comment: C or C++? They are not the same language. I'd assume C++ because XUL itself is C++...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to write a standalone (not under XULRunner) c/c++ application (Windows OS) that uses XUL as its backend GUI library.

The usual way to create a XUL GUI on top of a C++ application is by writing a XULRunner application with the C++ code wrapped in an XPCOM plugin.

You can make your application "stand-alone" by creating an installer program that copies the XULRunner runtime together with the XPCOM plugin to the user's computer. This is how <strike>GStreamer</strike> [SongBird](http://www.getsongbird.com/)  works, for example.

Comment: and how do i create a c++ application on top of XUL GUI ? in other words that uses XUL GUI ?

Comment: You can't write a C++ application on top of XUL, it's the other way around. However, once a C++ XPCOM component has been loaded by the XUL application communication between XUL/JavaScript and XPCOM/C++ is possible through the XPIDL interface.